# Electron won't read application name

Tags: npm, electron

i am using:  node 5.1.1, Chromium 49.0.2623.75, and Electron 0.37.2.

My `package.json` have both `name` and `productName` set. And there is zero syntax errors.

If I start the application Electron starts up with it's default menu, and the application is called "Electron" (i can see it on the first menu item on OSX and if i call `app.getName() // returns "Electron"`

If i set `app.setName('correct name')` then it will work from that point on. But the default menu and the application name for the OS will always show "Electron".

The Electron manuals doesn't mention any case where package.json's name/productName won't be used. Is there any? the values i have are simply ascii strings.

I also tried to checkout the electron-quick-start repo, and there the application is also called "Electron" there. I noticed it only had `name` set in package.json, so i also add `productName` to the same disappointing result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose you are using `electron-prebuild` and because it's a prebuild app (located on your `/node_modules/electron-prebuild/dist/Electron.app`) has it's own name (Electron).

To change the app name you have to rebuild/package your app and it will use the "name" or "productName" from your `package.json`.

To package your app you can use `electron-packager` here: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager

Comment: Ok, but how do you change it while developing.I have several Apps under development and they end up using same App name and therefore same folder under Application Support on osx.

Comment: I tried to do app.setName before loading windows but electron-store and electron-windows-state still saves configs under the 'Electron' folder, and not under the set app name